# hiredis redisCommand returns null for everything on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: c, arm, hiredis, raspberry-pi4

I have Raspberry pi 4B with latest raspbian and updated software. I installed `hiredis` library from github source using their installation instructions. When I try to run following code on normal computer, everything works fine but on Raspberry Pi 4B `redisCommand` always returns null. When I use `SET` command, database is updated.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <hiredis/hiredis.h>


int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    redisReply *reply;
    redisContext *c;

    c = redisConnect("127.0.0.1", 6379);
    if (c->err) {
        printf("error: %s\n", c->errstr);
        return 1;
    }


    /* Set a key */
    reply = redisCommand(c,"SET %s %s", "test", "Hello World");
    printf("SET: %s\n", reply->str);
    printf("error: %s\n", c->errstr);
    freeReplyObject(reply);

    redisFree(c);
    return 0;
}
```

Compilation: `gcc redis-test-rw.c -o redis-test-rw -g -lhiredis`

Run:

```
pi@rpi:~ $ ./redis-test-rw 
SET: (null)
error: 
pi@rpi:~ $
```

Redis after this call:

```
pi@rpi:~ $ redis-cli 
127.0.0.1:6379> GET test
"Hello World"
127.0.0.1:6379> 
pi@rpi:~ $
```

Redis `MONITOR` command:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> MONITOR
OK
1577573389.883836 [0 127.0.0.1:47228] "SET" "test" "Hello World"
```

I am really confused about this because on previous Raspberry pi 3B I had no problems with hiredis and on computer it's also all right.

Thanks for advance!

Edit:
Valgrind report:

```
$ valgrind ./redis-test-rw 
==21969== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==21969== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==21969== Using Valgrind-3.15.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==21969== Command: ./redis-test-rw
==21969== 
==21969== Invalid read of size 8
==21969==    at 0x4865004: ??? (in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem-v7l.so)
==21969==  Address 0x49f964c is 36 bytes inside a block of size 42 alloc'd
==21969==    at 0x4847690: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:309)
==21969==    by 0x48907BB: redisvFormatCommand (in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libhiredis.so.0.14)
==21969== 
SET: (null)
error: 
==21969== 
==21969== HEAP SUMMARY:
==21969==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==21969==   total heap usage: 23 allocs, 23 frees, 1,913 bytes allocated
==21969== 
==21969== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==21969== 
==21969== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==21969== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: What happens while you `MONITOR` the database in `redis-cli` and execute the code ? Just to assert that on my notebook your code works ok too.

Comment: @Niloct This is printed by `MONITOR`: `1577573389.883836 [0 127.0.0.1:47228] "SET" "test" "Hello World"`.

Comment: It's a bit weird because the `reply` is `NULL` when there is an error, instead of `reply->str` being `NULL`: https://github.com/redis/hiredis/blob/master/hiredis.c#L1060

Comment: So `reply->str` when `reply` is `NULL` should be a segfault.

Comment: How did you install hiredis on 4B ?

Comment: @Niloct Yeah, whole this thing is weird because it worked on rpi3B. Installation:
`git clone ..`, `make`, `sudo make install`, `sudo ldconfig`

Comment: @Niloct I added `valgrind` output if it is useful for something.

Comment: Sorry I can't think of anything else. Double check that your code is exactly what you've posted, because when `redisCommand` returns `NULL` on an error, that would trigger a segfault when you try to print `reply->str` (I just reproduced it here).

Comment: @Niloct maybe `reply` is not null but just `reply->str`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compile this sample code and verify the results:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <hiredis/hiredis.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    redisReply *reply;
    redisContext *c;

    c = redisConnect("127.0.0.1", 6379);
    if (c->err) {
        printf("error: %s\n", c->errstr);
        return 1;
    }

    /* PINGs */
    reply = redisCommand(c,"PING %s", "Hello World");
    printf("RESPONSE: %s\n", reply->str);
    printf("error: %s\n", c->errstr);
    freeReplyObject(reply);

    redisFree(c);
    return 0;
}
```

Should print:

```
RESPONSE: Hello World
error:
```

Comment: And monitoring it ?

Comment: Monitor looks right:
`1577577229.982302 [0 127.0.0.1:47586] "PING" "Hello World"`

Comment: Wipe out your hiredis installation, download https://github.com/redis/hiredis/archive/v0.13.3.zip and compile and try this version.

Comment: Oh, I didn't use release version but version from master branch. v0.14 works well too, there is probably mistake in non-release version. Everything works like a charm now, thank you very much for your help!